# Multiline textbox in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

How i can set multiline property for silverlight textbox?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Like this:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="true" />
```

Comment: I just love it when there is an easy answer :D

Answer (score 14):

Try this out....

```
<TextBox Height="300" Width="400" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" x:Name="txtResponse" Text=""></TextBox>
```